# Squid rate-limiting

Tags: squid

I want to limit the number of requests that we get from single IPs, using squid (assume I have to use squid for political reasons), blocking those that make too many requests in a set period of time.

I was considering writing a short Perl script and an external_acl_type, with a delay pool, but I am unsure as to what parameters I can pass to the helper function.

something like:

external_acl_type rate_limit /usr/bin/squid-access-control dst

but I am not sure if that would work?

Comment: How many users do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution I came up with, which I think is quite worth documenting, is as follows:

- Squid logs all of the requests it receives
- For CDN requests, squid follows the X-forwarded-For header, leaving the actual client IP in
  the logs
- Fail2ban checks the logs, recording how many requests are being made by clients per minute etc
- When a client makes X number of requests, it is put into the [squirm](http://squirm.foote.com.au) IP list, which has the request rewritten to point to a webserver on the loadbalancer.
- Squid picks this up, denies this request access to the actual webservers and allows them access to a thttpd server running on the loadbalancer, which hosts a webpage of "you're banned!"